# Use HTML Link in InnerHTML to display that file in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, innerhtml

I want to display the links that are stored in a json file like this:

```
[
    {
        "heading": "Waswas",
        "content": "./waswas.html"
    },

    {
        "heading": "Flu",
        "content":""
    }
]
```

In my component.ts file I parse that to an array variable like this:

```
 public treatmentsList:{heading: string, content: string}[] = treatments;
```

Then in my component.html file I have this:

```
<div>
    <h1>
        {{treatmentsList[0].heading}}
    </h1>
    <span [innerHTML]="getContent(treatmentsList[0].content) | async"></span>
</div>
```

But it shows the link instead of the file

The component.ts file:

```js
import { Content } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ContentService } from '../content.service';
import treatments from "./treatments.json"

var heading = "hTempl"
@Component({
  selector: 'app-treatment',
  templateUrl: './treatment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./treatment.component.css']
})

export class TreatmentComponent implements OnInit {
 public treatmentsList:{heading: string, content: string}[] = treatments;
  
 constructor(
  private readonly contentService: ContentService
)  {}

public getContent(path: string): Observable<SafeHtml> {
  return this.contentService.get(path);
}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TreatmentComponent } from './treatment/treatment.component';
import { PrgrefComponent } from './prgref/prgref.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TreatmentComponent,
    PrgrefComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You'll need to in-line the html in the JSON file, or do an http request to get the html document within your component.ts.

Comment: @JohnD I don't want to put it in the son for IDE Features.

Comment: Then you'll need to build a service to fetch the html files and then sanitize them with the dom sanitizer. If you post your full component.ts and component.html I can help further.

Comment: @JohnD How do I do that?

Comment: I posted an answer, reply if you have questions.

Comment: @JohnD I added that file with the same name as you said in the answer in the same directory as the same component said in the question, and is still not working.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser, are you getting an error there? Any console errors?

Comment: @JohnD I thought  I only needed to add this new thing called a service and it should work then because I thought that the only thing you posted was that. Then looking again at it I realized that you gave me more code that I wrote but it gave me a constructor error that I solved by adding `{}` after the `)` on the constructor; but when I refresh the page it is blank. .

Comment: Post your component.ts and any console errors

Comment: @JohnD No errors. The component.ts file is in the question.

Comment: That can't be the entire component.ts file, I can't help you further without additional portions of your component.ts or a console/network error message.

Comment: @JohnD, Sorry for late reply; I wrote the code in the post but it was not there, I could have not clicked the save button or some evil person removed it. I have put the whole file at the end of the question now.

Comment: Your component.ts looks good, can you update the component.html as well? Have you tried changing `"content": "./waswas.html"` to `"content": "/waswas.html"`?

Comment: You may also need to import `HttpClientModule` as described here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @John It now says [object Object].

Comment: Getting closer at least. Update your question with the modified code please.

Comment: @John I only changed the `app.module.ts` file and included it at the end of the question.

Comment: Can you confirm if you're `component.html` has been updated to use the `| async` as well?

Comment: @John Sorry for very late reply'; I have added the `| async` to the code in the html, now it is displaying nothing, only the rest of the site.

Comment: Can you add the updated component.html to your question?

Comment: @John I have changed it now.

Comment: That all looks correct, try wrapping your `<span>` in `<ng-template [ngIf]="getContent(treatmentsList[0].content) | async as html"><span [InnerHTML]="html">`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a service to fetch your html documents and then sanitize them.

content.service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ContentService {
  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
    private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  public get(path: string): Observable<SafeHtml> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'text/plain',
    });
    return this.http.get(path, {
      headers,
      responseType: 'text'
    }).pipe(
      // This is unsafe if the path and content is not under your control
      map(html => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html))
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your component.ts use the service

```js
constructor(
  private readonly contentService: ContentService
)

public getContent(path: string): Observable<SafeHtml> {
  return this.contentService.get(path);
}
```

Finally your html

```html
<span [InnerHTML]="getContent(treatmentsList[0].content) | async"></span>
```